# ShouldAutoplay on MoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, autoplay

I am a new developer, therefore I'm still learning and know I'm doing some things wrong. I have a segmented control object in which when the user presses one of the segments, it goes to play a video. I have it setup to where they press the segment, then have to press a play button to get the video to play. I want to cut out the play button and have it play automatically. This is where I'm having trouble. I found the shouldAutoplay option but when I use it and cut out the button, it won't take me to the video at all. I'm sure I'm not using the shouldAutoplay option correctly. Was hoping for some help or at least a point in the right direction.

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender;

{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"mytestimony" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie autorelease];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `[theMovie play];`?

**UPDATE:** I just noticed you set `shouldAutoplay` in `theMovie`, but what you presented is another instance of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, which is `moviePlayer`. That's why your movie did not autoplay. You should instead have:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't play the video, just prepare it for playing and put the `shouldAutoPlay` as `NO`, because you don't want to video player to play it automatically.

```
-(void) SetVideoFile:(NSString *)fileName {

    videoFileName=fileName;
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileName]];

    moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame ;
    [orientationHandler VideoStart];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view] ;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
}

-(void)moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // your custom code which you want to play after the player did finish playing
}
```

Comment: Please use Ctrl+K to indent your code by 4 spaces, so that it display properly. Thanks.